# drag drop mysql web form builder

Tags: forms, webforms, mysql, oracleforms

I would like to have a tool with which I can easily develop(dragNdrop) front-end for mysql table and publish it to web.  I am not sure whether I can try oracle forms, as my database is MySQL. Even if I can use Oracle forms to connect to MySQL, I would like to know any other third party tool which can do the job easily & quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I have used MySQL front for this before which I prefer comparing to phpmyadmin and such, found it at http://www.brothersoft.com/mysql-front-80299.html. I recommend it.